# Sharepoint: Send email to workflow initiator on reassignment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have created SharePoint designer workflow in which i am using approval action. 
How can i send email to workflow initiator when the task is reassigned to another approver?

Comment: Is your question how to check that the task was reassigned or how to include the person who created an item that initiated the workflow?

Comment: I want to send email when a task is reassigned

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a column (something like "old_approver"). Hide it from the view.
2. Create a workflow that starts every time an item is created and just copies the value from Approver column to old_approver.
3. In your workflow that fires every time an item is changed, add if statement to see if Approver = old_approver. If it's not, do your send email action.
4. Add another step to set old_approver to the new Approver value, so that they would have the same value again.

Done! I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The OP is asking a simple question in very clear English.

He wants to customize the built-in Reassignment process so that the new approver receives a task email.

Modifying this or the Request Changes process actions of the "Start an approval" activity is not possible. You would need to create your own approval workflow from scratch, preferably using custom code.

This is one of several limitations with the OOTB approval workflow.